# how to filter an array on condition like SQL IN clause using lodash?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I am trying to filter data which are present in an array using lodash. I am trying to filter like SQL IN clause.

```
ex: - select * from Test where id IN (2,4,5,67);
```

**JSON:**

```
storedData = [
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "name" : "ABC"
    },
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "name" : "XYZ"
    },
    {
        "id" : 3,
        "name" : "BVX"
    },
    {
        "id" : 4,
        "name" : "OOO"
    }
]
```

**Search criteria:**

```
[2,4,5,67]
```

**Required Output:**

```
output = [
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "name" : "XYZ"
    },
    {
        "id" : 4,
        "name" : "OOO"
    }
]
```

Below is my code which i tried to implement

```
output = _.filter(storedData, (value) => {
    return value.id == 2 || value.id == 4 || value.id == 5 || value.id == 67
});
```

Could you please help me how to filter like IN clause ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the intersection between the two arrays using [`intersectionWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/#intersectionWith), which allows you to provide a callback and will keep all elements from the first array which the callback returns `true` for.

See example below:

```js
const storedData = [ { "id" : 1, "name" : "ABC" }, { "id" : 2, "name" : "XYZ" }, { "id" : 3, "name" : "BVX" }, { "id" : 4, "name" : "OOO" } ];
const search = [2,4,5,67];

const res = _.intersectionWith(storedData, search, (o, n) => o.id === n); 
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.includes`

```
_.filter(storedData, (value) => _.includes(criteria, value.id))
```

```js
const storedData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "ABC",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "XYZ",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "BVX",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "OOO",
  },
]

const criteria = [2, 4, 5, 67]

const output = _.filter(storedData, (value) => _.includes(criteria, value.id))

console.log(output)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```